# Function in Postgres - Ignore first occurences of a value based on a column

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling with this function and cannot manage to achieve the wanted result, I thought it would be time to ask...

Here's a a brief summary of the function:

1. It retrieves duration limit parameters (days and date) from a table named "properties."
2. It constructs a dynamic SQL query to fetch and process records from
   a table named "fact_entriesexits" based on certain conditions,
   including date and device type.
3. It processes the retrieved records to identify pairs of entry and departure events and inserts corresponding records into a table named "fact_parkingtransaction."
4. It raises notices for various scenarios, including successfully inserted records and unexpected data conditions.
5. Finally, it updates the "DURATION.LIMIT.DATE" property in the "properties" table and raises a notice to indicate the update.

Now here's the tricky part. The function is supposed to fetch entry and exit times from the fact_entriesexits table. However, if an entry of a specific cardnumber is followed by an entry with the same cardnumber, the first entry should be ignored.

- Entries are of devicetype 1
- Exits are of devicetype 2

Some sample data:

```
devicetype|cardnumber|eventdate              |
----------+----------+-----------------------+
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 13:47:06.000|
         2|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:31:00.000|
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:32:26.000|
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:33:33.000|
         2|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:37:25.000|
         1|00D56029  |2023-07-25 14:20:56.000|
         2|00D56029  |2023-07-25 16:26:53.000|
```

As visible here, there are two occurrences of entries after each other for the same cardnumber. This means that according to my function, the first entry (2023-05-02 15:32:26.000) should be ignored.

**Expected Output**

- Row 1: Entry 2023-05-02 13:47:06.000 | Exit: 2023-05-02 15:31:00.000
- Row 2: Entry 2023-05-02 15:33:33.000 | Exit: 2023-05-02 15:37:25.000
- Row 3: Entry 2023-07-25 14:20:56.000 | Exit: 2023-07-25 16:26:53.000

**Actual Output**

- Row 1: Entry 2023-05-02 13:47:06.000 | Exit: 2023-05-02 15:31:00.000
- Row 2: Entry 2023-05-02 15:32:28.000 | Exit: 2023-05-02 15:37:25.000
- Row 3: Entry 2023-07-25 14:20:56.000 | Exit: 2023-07-25 16:26:53.000

**The function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.desi3()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    arrived_entry RECORD;
    departed_entry RECORD;  
    durationLimitDays INTEGER := -1;
    durationLimitDate TIMESTAMP := '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
    cursorQuery text;
    cursorEvent refcursor;
    maxEventTime TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  -- Get the duration limit parameters
  SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDays FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS';
  SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDate FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';

  cursorQuery := '
    WITH filtered_entries AS (
      SELECT
        id,
        facilitykey,
        systeminterfacekey,
        devicekey,
        datekey,
        timekey,
        tickettypekey,
        eventtypekey,
        manufacturerkey,
        devicetype,
        licenseplate,
        licenseplatekey,
        cardnumber,
        eventdate,
        etlsource,
        LAG(devicetype) OVER (PARTITION BY cardnumber ORDER BY eventdate) AS prev_devicetype,
        LEAD(devicetype) OVER (PARTITION BY cardnumber ORDER BY eventdate) AS next_devicetype
      FROM
        fact_entriesexits
      WHERE
        eventdate >= ' || quote_literal(durationLimitDate) || '
        AND devicetype IN (1, 2)
    ),
    valid_entries AS (
      SELECT
        fe.*,
        CASE
          WHEN devicetype = 1 AND (prev_devicetype IS NULL OR prev_devicetype = 2 OR (next_devicetype = 1 AND LEAD(next_devicetype) OVER (PARTITION BY cardnumber ORDER BY eventdate) = 2)) THEN 1
          WHEN devicetype = 2 AND (next_devicetype IS NULL OR next_devicetype = 1 OR prev_devicetype = 1) THEN 2
          ELSE NULL
        END AS startend
      FROM
        filtered_entries AS fe
    )
    SELECT * FROM valid_entries
    WHERE startend IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM fact_parkingtransaction AS fp
      WHERE fp.eventid_arrival = valid_entries.id
      OR fp.eventid_departure = valid_entries.id
    )
    ORDER BY cardnumber, eventdate';

  OPEN cursorEvent SCROLL FOR EXECUTE cursorQuery;

  LOOP
    FETCH cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    IF arrived_entry.startend = 1 THEN
      FETCH cursorEvent INTO departed_entry;
      IF departed_entry.startend = 2 THEN
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO fact_parkingtransaction (
            id,
            entryfacilitykey,
            exitfacilitykey,
            systeminterfacekey,
            manufacturerkey,
            tickettypekey,
            entrydatekey,
            entrytimekey,
            exitdatekey,
            exittimekey,
            entrydevicekey,
            exitdevicekey,
            entrytime,
            exittime,
            duration,
            eventid_arrival,
            eventid_departure,
            cardnumber,
            licenseplate,
            licenseplatekey,
            dateinserted,
            etlsource
          ) VALUES (
            nextval(''fact_parkingtransaction_id_seq''),
            ' || arrived_entry.facilitykey || ',
            ' || departed_entry.facilitykey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.systeminterfacekey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.manufacturerkey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.tickettypekey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.datekey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.timekey || ',
            ' || departed_entry.datekey || ',
            ' || departed_entry.timekey || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.devicekey || ',
            ' || departed_entry.devicekey || ',
            ''' || arrived_entry.eventdate || ''',
            ''' || departed_entry.eventdate || ''',
            ' || date_part('epoch', departed_entry.eventdate::timestamp - arrived_entry.eventdate::timestamp) || ',
            ' || arrived_entry.id || ',
            ' || departed_entry.id || ',
            ''' || arrived_entry.cardnumber || ''',
            ''' || arrived_entry.licenseplate || ''',
            ' || arrived_entry.licenseplatekey || ',
            ''' || current_timestamp || ''',
            ''' || arrived_entry.etlsource || '''
          )';
        RAISE NOTICE 'New record inserted into fact_parkingtransaction for card number ''%''', arrived_entry.cardnumber;
      ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected entry after entry found at event id ''%'' and card number ''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.cardnumber;
      END IF;
    ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected card number or car park change found at event id ''%'' and card number ''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.cardnumber;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursorEvent;

  EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM fact_entriesexits WHERE eventdate >= ' || quote_literal(durationLimitDate) INTO maxEventTime;
  durationLimitDate := maxEventTime - interval '1 day' * durationLimitDays;
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE properties SET PROP_VALUE = ' || quote_literal(durationLimitDate) || ' WHERE prop_key = ''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE''';
  RAISE NOTICE 'Updated DURATION.LIMIT.DATE to ''%''', durationLimitDate;
END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: Pls focus on the *tricky part* the rest is not such interesting;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use analytic function `lead` to validate the entries.

A `devicetype = 1` must be followed by `2` and vice versa.
The last device type must be `2`, so setting the *default* for the last row to `1` you may simple validate with the predicate

`devicetype != devicetype_lead`

**Example**

```
with tab as (
select * from (values
(1, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-05-02 13:47:06.000'),
(2, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-05-02 15:31:00.000'),
(1, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-05-02 15:32:26.000'), 
(1, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-05-02 15:33:33.000'),
(2, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-05-02 15:37:25.000'),
(1, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-07-25 14:20:56.000'),
(2, '00D56029',timestamp'2023-07-25 16:26:53.000')
) tab(devicetype, cardnumber,eventdate)
), tab2 as (
select 
 tab.*,
 lead(devicetype,1,1) over (partition by cardnumber order by eventdate) devicetype_lead,
 devicetype != lead(devicetype,1,1) over (partition by cardnumber order by eventdate) is_valid
from tab)
select * from tab2
order by eventdate

devicetype|cardnumber|eventdate          |devicetype_lead|is_valid|
----------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------+
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 13:47:06|              2|true    |
         2|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:31:00|              1|true    |
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:32:26|              1|false   |
         1|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:33:33|              2|true    |
         2|00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:37:25|              1|true    |
         1|00D56029  |2023-07-25 14:20:56|              2|true    |
         2|00D56029  |2023-07-25 16:26:53|              1|true    |
```

The rest is *as simple as* filter only valid data, get the LEAD timestamp and filter only the starting rows with  `devicetype = 1`

**Query (without sample data)**

```
with tab2 as (
select 
 tab.*,
 lead(devicetype,1,1) over (partition by cardnumber order by eventdate) devicetype_lead,
 devicetype != lead(devicetype,1,1) over (partition by cardnumber order by eventdate) is_valid
from tab),
tab3 as (
select devicetype, cardnumber, eventdate start_date,
lead(eventdate) over (partition by cardnumber order by eventdate) stop_date
from tab2
where is_valid)
select cardnumber, start_date, stop_date from tab3
where devicetype = 1
order by start_date


cardnumber|start_date         |stop_date          |
----------+-------------------+-------------------+
00D56029  |2023-05-02 13:47:06|2023-05-02 15:31:00|
00D56029  |2023-05-02 15:33:33|2023-05-02 15:37:25|
00D56029  |2023-07-25 14:20:56|2023-07-25 16:26:53|
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it following your example.